# All common divisors of $8n + 3$ and $5n + 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n$ is just a natural number. I've been scratching my head over this one for a while, so, I thought I'd seek a little help. 
My line of thinking is $8n + 3$ is always an odd number, which means, only an odd number can divide it. Thus the only overlapping divisors of $8n + 3$ and $5n + 2$ are odd numbers. But, I can't seem to make the next logical jump as to what this implies. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the Euclidean algorithm on polynomials. I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $8\cdot(5n+2)-5\cdot(8n+3)=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ 8(5n+2)-5(8n+3) = 1  \    $ is divisible by any common divisor of $\ 5n+2,\ 8n+3.\, $ This Bezout Identity  can be found by eliminating $\,n,\,$ or by the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

For the latter, using the verson of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) yields

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
8n+3 & 1 & 0\\
5n+2 & 0 & 1\\
3n+1 & 1 & -1\\
2n+1 &-1 & 2\\
 n   & 2 & -3\\
 1   &\color{#c00}{-5} & \color{#0a0}8\\
\end{array}\qquad\quad$$

where above lines $\,\ a\ \ b\ \ c\ \,$ mean  $\ a = b(8n+3) + c(5n+2).\ $ So the Bezout identity is

$$ 1 \,=\, \color{#c00}{-5}(8n+3)+ \color{#0a0}{8}(5n+2)\quad $$

The linked post describes the algorithm in great detail, in a way that is easy to remember.

Comment: The bezout identity is gcd = ax + by. Now, if that's the case and the gcd is 1, then that's the only common divisor they share, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay, but, I'm not sure how to use the extended euclidean algorithm with those two equations. I googled it, but not luck. Do I just divide the two equations?

Comment: @zachary See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed link! It all makes sense now :)